# Calling a Web API page from SSIS?

Tags: asp.net, ssis, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a simple ASP.Net Web API set up that triggers a process. I would like to call this API from SSIS. I am able to call a web service but am not sure how to call an API link since there is no WSDL.

Is there a way to do this without having to use AxtiveX scripting?

Comment: Have you tried using `WebClient` from a script task? Which version of SSIS?

Comment: SQL 2008 SP3. I'm not familiar with or seeing WebClient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this before, but you could create a **Script Task** and use [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.85).aspx) by referencing `System.Web`.  If you take a look at [Calling Web Api service from a .NET 2.0 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483182/calling-web-api-service-from-a-net-2-0-client), you should be able to amend this to call your *Web API*.

This is a stab in the dark, and I might get downvoted, but it might be a starting point.

**EDIT**: I did some more digging around, and found a similar question here, it's not calling a Web API, but it is making a HTP Request etc [How to make an HTTP request from SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684317/how-to-make-an-http-request-from-ssis)

Answer (score 1):

Another stab in the dark here, since I haven't tried this either...

Use ChristianDev's method to retrieve the XML and store it in a variable to use with the XML source.