# Send SMS from SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ssis, sms

I am new to using SSIS and I am looking for a way to send messages using SMS. Is this possible to do? And if yes, is there a way to use a Web API in SSIS to send SMS messages?

Comment: Not sure about the Web API part, but it is possible to send an SMS using SQL Server alerts: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2922/sql-server-alerts-with-text-messaging-from-sql-server-database-mail/

Comment: If you are talking about for admin purposes sending an email to a SMS address such as the link provided by DenStudent is the easiest way to go, if you are wanting to send out mass text messages it can be done but you would have to have a script task and a message gateway capable of sending them.  So if you have the latter in the form of an API you would just use a script task to interact with the API

Comment: what i got from your comment is that if i got web api for sending sms , it will be done. if it is can u provide me with example how i will use this web api in script task ?

Answer (score 0):

After i did more search i found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483182/calling-web-api-service-from-a-net-2-0-client)
and his first answer was what i want.

the second part of my  Question was about api to use i found this 2 api

1. [Nexmo](http://dashboard.nexmo.com)
2. [Infobip](http://www.infobip.com/) but you will have to contact them first

both of them will give you atest account to use it at first , but i used the first one from SQL SSIS.